# dynamic array allocation and copy to larger

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a homework assignment and I'm trying to figure out a good way about this.

**I want to copy a dynamic array of type say "dog" that contains values from two structs to another "temporary" dynamic array twice the size. Once complete, I want the original array name to replace the "temporary"**

```
pseudo: 
user inserts some newnum of elements ->call to func
check if sizeof(array) < (n_items + newnum)
yes: need to grow array
//here's the trouble part
create temp.array 2x sizeof(dog.array), copy dog.array to bigger temp.array
//would i be better off free(dog.array) and then create a new instance of
//dog.array that is now the same size of the temp.array and copy again/free(temp)
//or is there another method to do "new" dog.array = temp.array
```

When my program checks for room to insert more values into this array, it will go ahead and allocate a new array of twice the size if the first one is full. After this it swaps out the data in a for loop which is fine. I am curious how to go about freeing the old allocated space and then renaming the new "temp" array to match the old ones...or maybe just delete the data associated with the old array, and simply make a pointer of same name to the "temp" one.  Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Take a look at the `realloc()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), which lets you change the amount of memory allocated to your pointer of interest. Or you could do a [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) on a second, distinct pointer, [`memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) bytes from the first pointer to the second, and then [`free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) the first pointer. It's up to you.

Comment: Why would you want to use malloc here rather than realloc?

Comment: thanks I forgot to mention I was instructed not to use realloc

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What if you have a homework assignment to do?

Comment: @Alex Question did not mention this artificial constraint. It should have done. Without the  constraint realloc would always be preferred.

Comment: I think there was a 'homework' tag, but in any case I was just joking around.

Comment: well either way alex was correct on both accounts, and both are viable options for certain situations. mine was a priority queue / heap /heap sort. so i just went with a memcopy.  I think i should have stated that i understood i could use either i was just unsure as to how to deref one pointer to another when they are built on several combined structs and what not. I was unsure if shallow copy would suffice